# How can I give each array in a multidimensional array a unique identifier?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some paths inside my database

```
mylist/folder1/horse/fred
mylist/folder1/cat/john
mylist/folder2/cat/sam
mylist/folder2/cat/cat/john
```

I am creating  an array with a tree structure:

```
function explodeTree($array, $delimiter = "_", $baseval = false) {
    if(!is_array($array)) return false;
    $splitRE = "/" . preg_quote($delimiter, "/") . "/";
    $returnArr = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $parts = preg_split($splitRE, $key, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $leafPart = array_pop($parts);
        $parentArr = &$returnArr;
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (!isset($parentArr[$part])) {
                $parentArr[$part] = array();
            } elseif (!is_array($parentArr[$part])) {
                if ($baseval) {
                    $parentArr[$part] = array("__base_val" => $parentArr[$part]);
                } else {
                    $parentArr[$part] = array();
                }
            }
            $parentArr = &$parentArr[$part];
        }
        if (empty($parentArr[$leafPart])) {
            $parentArr[$leafPart] = $val;
        } elseif ($baseval && is_array($parentArr[$leafPart])) {
            $parentArr[$leafPart]["__base_val"] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $returnArr;
}

$sql = "SELECT path, path FROM mylist WHERE id = ?";  
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$id]);
$array = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$tree = explodeTree($array, "/");
```

The result is

```
array(1) {
  ["mylist"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["folder1"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["horse"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fred"]=>
        string(30) "mylist/folder1/horse/fred"
      }
      ["cat"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["john"]=>
        string(28) "mylist/folder1/cat/john"
      }
    }
    ["folder2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["cat"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["sam"]=>
        string(27) "mylist/folder2/cat/sam"
        ["cat"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["john"]=>
          string(32) "mylist/folder2/cat/cat/john"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to give each array a unique identifier? 
It is important because later I need to look for example for the specific array `cat`. But `cat` exists multiple times, and right now I cannot identity which `cat` I am looking for.

Comment: All arrays have an unique identifier, always. It s the keys chaining  based on hierarchy.

Comment: The index of the array can/should be your database ID, like e.g. `petID`. So your arrays' first index looks something like ARRAY[<petID_1>]=ARRAY('cat', ....). Done that you can directly access any petID with `$arr[$petID]`.

Comment: @djot Ok, when I understood you right I need to write `$sql = "SELECT path, petID FROM mylist WHERE id = ?";  `

Comment: @djot but then my result is `["john"]=>
          string(4) "1234"` so the petID is only working for the last element of the path `in this case `john`. I cannot give the pedID to `cat`

Comment: ["mylist"]["folder1"]["horse"]["fred"] is a chained key. While using nested foreach , simply implement a different $key ($key1(mylist) ,$key2(folder1)etc). Do your stuff and modify the element in the array by $array[$key1][$key2]= mystuff.

Comment: @cpugourou Yes, this is exactly what I would like to do, but I have no idea how to get `key1` to `mylist`

Comment: In your last nested foreach, Concat the keys the same way of your path. $key1."/".$key2."/".$key3."/"; you can then add an element at the array root or either push it into another array depending on your condition.

Comment: @cpugourou Can you give an example?

Comment: @Jarla Can you please provide some more of your "paths" and then an array, on how you expect these splitted parts to look like?

Comment: @dijot All kind of paths that you can imagine are possible from `1/2/3/4/.../1000/1001` to `world/countries/africa/people/man/james/...` to `store/apple/computer/imac/user/number/12`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `petID` as index into the array after the sql_query.

```
while ($row = $this->stmt->fetch()) {
    $pet_array[$row[petID]] = $row;
}
```

For just 2 selected columns, you could use `array_column()` instead of the `while` loop on a already completely fetched `$pet_array`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

```
$pet_array = array_column($pet_array, 'cat', 'petID'); // this will only hold $arr[petID] = 'Fred'; so no paths, etc.
```

Comment: Where exactly in my function do you mean to put this?

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. Can you give an example for my function?

Comment: Best thing you can do imho, is to split up e.g. `mylist/folder2/cat/sam` in different database columns. That way the use of a database makes sense. Then you can select whatever you like and return it without a the need of a `explodeTree` function.

Comment: Why is not simply something possible like this in a mutlidimensional array `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => mylist
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => folder1
        )

)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function explodeTree($array, $delimiter = "_", $baseval = false) {
    if(empty($array)) return false; // checks for false, null, 0, "0", and empty array
    $splitRE = "/" . preg_quote($delimiter, "/") . "/";
    $returnArr = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $parts = preg_split($splitRE, $val['path'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

        $returnArr[$val['id']] = $parts;
        //$returnArr[$val['id']] = ARRAY('mylist'=>$parts[0], 'folder'=>$parts[1], 'pet'=>$parts[2], 'name'=>$parts[3]); // does only work for exactly for items (of same category)
    }
    return $returnArr;
}
```

So now, if you want to get the details of e.g. `pet` with `petID=4`, you can do this like:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, path FROM mylist WHERE id = ?";  
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$id]);
$array = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$tree = explodeTree($array, "/");
echo 'I am a '.$tree[4]['pet'].', and my name is '.$tree[4]['name'];
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, and what the `leaf` thing is. Perhaps you need to split up this 4-item array in 4 single item arrays. Or you have to put `petID` in as 5th item, and the later do an `array_search` for `petID` in this 5-item array.

Comment: Thank you, my paths are always changing. So somethimes I have for example this path `bithday/colors/blue/clouds`.  Is your solution still working?

Comment: I tested your function. But my result is: `array(1) {
  ["m"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mylist"]=>
    string(1) "m"
    ["folder"]=>
    NULL
    ["pet"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
}`

Comment: Well, your "structure" is ... no structure. How do you want to handle 4 or 6 parts, when you don't know if e.g. part 4 is a name, a folder or ...!?

Comment: Yes, the structure of the paths is always different. That's why I thought it is the best to have a unique id for every array element